# Trigger full reloading of the page in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have in my react application a button which trigger `history.push('/home')`. So, when user clicks the button the page should be changed with `history.push('/home')` from `useHistory`. So, this does not trigger a full reloading of the page, but i need.
Question: Is there a parameter that will force a full reloading after the user clicks the button?

Comment: I guess, you should be asking yourself about "why would you need to re-render?", "which exactly parts of the UI (components) should have different appearance, based on location or browsing history?". Then you would probably want to pass there corresponding props, trigger respective state updates and thus get it re-rendered.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov, i want to get the same effect like with `history.go(0)` but also to pass additionally my url.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov, i created a question with what i want to achieve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69103345/react-js-check-if-navigate-outside-the-page. Do you know how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Have a condition to check a variable in your Home component, make use of useState to force a render when that variable is updated.